# What's wrong with my code about linked list in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have created two classes namely Node and LinkedList. The code is compilable but it never produces the last data that I store in my linked list.

Consider these two classes

**Node.java**

```
public class Node {

private int id;
private String name;
private Node next;

public Node(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public Node(int id, String name, Node next) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.next = next;
}

}
```

**LinkedList.java**

```
public class LinkedList {

private Node start;

public LinkedList() {
    start = null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

    list.create(2345,"Peter");
    list.create(3001,"Mary");
    list.create(4763,"John");
    list.create(3863,"Johnny");

    list.display();
}

public void create(int id, String name) {
    if(start == null) {
    start = new Node(id, name, start);
    } 
    else {  
        Node temp = start;

    while(temp.getNext() != null) {
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
        Node newNode = new Node(id, name, null);
        temp.setNext(newNode);
    }
}


public void display() {
    if(start == null) {
        System.out.println("\nThe list is empty!");
    } 
    else {
        Node temp = start;

    while(temp.getNext() != null) {
        System.out.println("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    }
}

public void delete(int id, String name) {
    Node previous =  start;
    Node temp = start;

    while(temp.getID() != id) {
        if(temp.getNext() == null) {
            System.out.println("\nElement "+ id + " not found !");
        break;
    }

    while(temp.getName() != name) {
        if(temp.getNext() == null) {
            System.out.println("\nElement "+ name + " not found !");
        break;
    }

        previous = temp;
        temp = temp.getNext();

    }
    if(temp == start) {
        start = start.getNext();
    } 
    else {
        previous.setNext(temp.getNext());
    }
    }
}
}
```

In this case, the programme will produce all contents stored in the list but not the last one.

In other words, the following line is not displayed by the programme while the first three data stored can be outputted without any problem.

> list.create(3863,"Johnny");

May I know what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: t will be better to maintain `end` to be consistent with your `start` variable (or I would call it `tail`) to keep track of last `Node` in your `LinkedList` as you are adding new `Node`s there, this way you will not need to traverse the list every time you add new `Node`

Comment: Your problem is caused by your loop in display() method. Think about it: your last `Node` will NEVER have next entry...

Comment: Another minor note: you may as well get used to defining toString() method for your classes starting with your `Node` class - define it to return the formatted output as you use in your `LinkedList` `display()` method and you will be able to use  `System.out.println(Node);`

Comment: Thanks Germann! You have taught me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `temp.getNext()` twice in `display()`.
You can use:

```
public void display() {
    if(start == null) {
        System.out.println("\nThe list is empty!");
    } 
    else {
        Node temp = start;

        while(temp != null) {
            System.out.println("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

When you call `temp.getNext()` to check if the loop should be stopped, you miss the last element.

Comment: Thanks a lot whoAml! Appreciate that! =)

Answer (score 1):

In your display code, you are stopping before you print the last element:

```
else {
    Node temp = start;

    while(temp.getNext() != null) {
        System.out.println("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
}
```

The line, `while(temp.getNext() != null)` means that the `while` loop will not execute if the `temp.getNext()` is `null`, but the last element's `getNext()` is `null` because it's at the end of the list.  You need to add the line:

```
System.out.println("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
```

after the while loop to print the last element.

You are also executing `temp.getNext()` twice in that loop;  if you store the result in a local variable you won't have to call that method twice.

Comment: @josephineteo23 glad I could help. If this solved your problem, then you should mark it as accepted.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your while loop, try this

```
while(true) {

    System.out.println("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
    temp = temp.getNext();
    if(temp==null) break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   while(temp.getNext() != null) {
    System.out.println("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
    temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

This means that on your last node, the next node will be null, so the last node won't show.

So you simply need to add the print line after the while loop like so:

```
       while(temp.getNext() != null) {
    System.out.println("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
    temp = temp.getNext();
}
("ID : " + temp.getID() +  " Name : " + temp.getName());
```

Comment: Hi TangoKilo, thanks for your reply! May I know how to modify it to correctly output my last node?

Comment: If you add a print statement after the while loop you should get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
while(temp.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Then you will enter the loop too with the last element. You are loosing elements doing two times `getNetxt()`.

Comment: @josephineteo23 then you can vote to every single question with valuable information ;)